# Odd rake db:migrate output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-activerecord

Why does `rake db:migrate` run `Execute db:schema:dump` my output is all screwed up (showing SQL).

Looks like this:

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (3.7ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'accounts'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname

   (3.2ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'deliveries'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname

   (3.2ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'posts'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname
```

Trace shows this:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

This started after upgrading a rails 4.1.6 to rails 4.2.0.

Why is this occurring?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The schema dumper updates `schema.rb` and all those funky looking queries are used to figure out the table structures.

Comment: @mu this happens every time I run rake db:migrate ... I expect nothing to happen if migrations are current. I don't understand why I see this output...

Comment: It always runs as 'first_time'

Comment: @muistooshort Do you know what is causing it to dump schema like this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I use `structure.sql` though because I have all sorts of things in my database that ActiveRecord won't understand. Why is this a problem? What do you mean by "my output is all screwed up"?

Comment: @muistooshort to clarify I mean, running `rake db:migrate` should produce no output if migrations are current. Instead it produces what you see above and also it runs `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"` every time I run an rspec test, which is just odd behavior. The application works but this output is weirding me out. Make sense?

Comment: The `schema_migrations` SQL is run every time you `db:migrate`, `schema_migrations` is where AR keeps track of what migrations have been run. The other bits of SQL look like AR figuring out the schema of your models and that happens every time the model classes are loaded. If this only happens when you run tests then you probably have the logging too verbose in your test environment.

Comment: I have the same. I don't understand why in new version of rails there is so lot of output generated on each `rake db:migrate` . is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason I was getting this weird cryptic SQL'ish output is because I had Heroku's rails_12factor gem in my gemfile and not grouped to :production.

The solution was to do:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and run `bundle`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue after upgrading to Rails 4.2.1, preventing me from deploying with migrations via Codeship, which expects a very particular output from a `rake db:migrate` to consider a push successful.

Setting `config.log_level = :info` in `config/environments/production.rb` fixed the issue for me, presumably because the log level was too verbose at the `:debug` level.

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21051) solved the "odd" output for me:
Just set `dump_schema_after_migration` to `false` in your environment configuration like this:

**/config/environments/development.rb**

```
Application.configure do
  ...
  dump_schema_after_migration = false
  ...
end
```

---

**EDIT**
This is not what you want to do in most cases because you need to have the `schema.rb` in your version control.