# Rails: weird queries after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's been a while, but I only take care of this now.

In Rails 3.2, each time I run a migration (`rake db:migrate`), after the normal SQL logs for making the migration, I get a bunch of very confusing queries executed.

Here they are:

```
   (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ('20150623124632')
   (5.6ms)  COMMIT
   (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
   (5.9ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'addresses'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (4.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'authentications'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.3ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'balancing_transactions'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.6ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'billing_informations'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.4ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'bills'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.1ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'checkins'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'converters'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'copass_transactions'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'copasser_preferences'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'copassers'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_comments'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.0ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_copasser_interactions'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.1ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_event_type_associations'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_pictures'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.1ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_recommends'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.1ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_tag_votes'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.3ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_transaction_templates'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_type_associations'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.1ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospace_wishlists'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.1ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'cospaces'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'countries'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'coupons'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.4ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'currency_accounts'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (6.9ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'delayed_jobs'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.4ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'event_types'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'external_transactions'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.3ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'faqs'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.5ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'finances'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.4ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'friend_suggestions'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'friendship_notifications'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (9.0ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'friendships'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.4ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'group_copassers'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (6.9ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'groups'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.conname

   (5.2ms)  
 SELECT t2.relname AS to_table
 , a1.attname AS column
 , a2.attname AS primary_key
 , c.conname AS name
 , c.confdeltype AS dependency
 , c.confupdtype AS update_dependency
 , c.condeferrable AS deferrable
 , c.condeferred AS deferred
 , c.convalidated AS valid
 FROM pg_constraint c
 JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
 JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
 JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
 WHERE c.contype = 'f'
 AND t1.relname = 'in_progress_transactions'
 AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
 ORDER BY c.

# [TRUNKED BECAUSE OF Stackoverflow LIMITATION]
```

It never break anything since those are only `SELECT`s, but they are very ugly and prevent me from easily checking that everything went fine.

Any idea where this comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just looks like Rails crawling the schema to figure out the structure of your models. `db:migrate` is generally quiet, so the output may be due to the `rails_12factor` gem if you're using that (usually with Heroku). If that's it, you can use [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955822/odd-rake-dbmigrate-output) solution and just wrap that gem in a `:production` block, since it doesn't need to run in development.

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```